# What prevents RHEL7 default PAM config's "nullok" option from allowing empty passwords?

Tags: linux, authentication, pam

The config `/etc/pam.d/password-auth` is included by several `PAM` services including `sshd`. This is its `auth` stanza:

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        required      pam_deny.so
```

I must be misunderstanding the 2nd line because, looking at `man pam_unix` and `man pam.d`, it should effectively allow empty passwords:

```
   nullok
       The default action of this module is to not permit the user access to a service if their official
       password is blank. The nullok argument overrides this default.
```

However, even if I set a user with an empty password in `/etc/shadow`, I'm not able to log-in:

```
# grep johndoe /etc/shadow
johndoe::16335:0:99999:7:::
```

What am I missing in my understanding of how `PAM` and `pam_unix` work?

Comment: how are you logging in? `ssh`? `sshd` may choose to reject a blank password. do you have logs from the service you're using to log in?

Comment: Not at the office at the moment but I will look at the logs when I get in tomorrow morning. I was under the impression that `sshd` didn't do any inspection of credentials and it was all done by `PAM`.

Comment: This is not true.  An application may choose to do whatever it wishes with credentials before passing them to PAM.  See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `PermitEmptyPasswords` configuration option to sshd is set to deny empty passwords.  From `man 5 sshd_config`:

```
   PermitEmptyPasswords
          When password authentication is  allowed,  it  specifies  whether  the  server
          allows login to accounts with empty password strings.  The default is ``no''.
```

Key point: the default is to deny empty passwords over ssh.